# PHP MySQL Invalid Query bool(False)

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with a MySQL Database with two tables `up` and `info`. `up` has columns `ID` and `Password` and `info` has columns `ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, and `Reg` and `ID` joins the two tables. I am working in PHP and have this query which is giving me `bool(false)` on `var_dump` when I call it

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT up.Password FROM up INNER JOIN info ON info.ID = up.ID WHERE info.EMAIL = " . $email);
var_dump($result);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

The query works when I query `mysql` with that identical query and the variable `$email` returns a proper result when I call `var_dump` on it.

Comment: enclose `$email` with single quotes.  `WHERE info.EMAIL = '" . $email."'"`

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. I feel like the moron of the century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we use some text string in any clause in query. Always write with quotes.

like

```
$query  = "SELECT up.Password FROM up INNER JOIN info ON info.ID = up.ID WHERE info.EMAIL = '".$quer."'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```